# Alternative as Filter

Tags: javascript

I am mapping if Status has been found. The functionality seem to be working correctly but is there a shorter way or alternative way?

For example:

```
data = {
  Items: [
    {Id: 434, Status: "Processing"},
    {Id: 223, Status: "Completed"}
  ]
}

mapperData = {
  Id: 223, 
  Name: "Hello World",
  Status: data.Items.filter(function(item) {
      if (item.Id == 223) {
        return item.Status
      }
  })[0].Status,
}

console.log(mapperData)
```

Returned:

> {Id: 223, Name: "Hello World", Status: "Completed"}

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jgsr65pv/3/

Comment: For future reference, instead of an off-site Fiddle, you can make it easier for people to help you (and help yourself avoid leaving out important details) by using an **on-site** Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the `[0]`, use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
Status: data.Items.find(function(item) { return item.Id == 223; }).Status
```

E.g.:

```
mapperData = {
  Id: 223, 
  Name: "Hello World",
  Status: data.Items.find(function(item) { return item.Id == 223; }).Status,
}
```

Even better with an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
mapperData = {
  Id: 223, 
  Name: "Hello World",
  Status: data.Items.find(item => item.Id == 223).Status,
}
```

`find` was added in ES2015, but can easily be polyfilled for obsolete environments like IE11.

Comment: Crowder, would it not be wise to add an undefined check?

Comment: @callback: There's none in the question, so I assume none is necessary -- e.g., the author knows that the array will contain an item with that `Id`.

Comment: Also, you almost always want to use `===` operator instead of `==`.

Comment: @BoltKey: No, it almost never matters. It's a matter of style, not substance, in the vast majority of cases. I copied the OP's style.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to go with a `forEach` loop on `Items` array and set your `id` to compare in a variable:

```js
var data = {
  Items: [
    {Id: 434, Status: "Processing"},
    {Id: 223, Status: "Completed"}
  ]
}

var res = {};
var id = 223;
data.Items.forEach((item)=>{
  res.Id = id;
  res.Name =  "Hello World";
  if (item.Id == id) {
    res.Status = item.Status
  }
});


console.log(res)
```